# fixed position of two dynamic boxes in WordPress theme during the scrolling the page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress-theming, bootstrap-4

I have a sidebar in the WordPress theme which i can add multiple dynamic box there. I want to highlighted 2 boxes by fixing their positions at the top of the page during the scrolling, but I don't want to add position:fixed by jquery because the theme is responsive and I don't want to change the layout in different views. 
I have used Affix plugin of Bootstrap but, unfortunately it fixed all the boxes,
You can find the code here:

```
<div class="row post-detail">
<div class="col-md-9 right">
    <?php $thumbnail = $util->main->get_post_thumbnail_data($post_id); ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 left" id="myScrollspy">
    <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="205">
        <!-- I WANT TO ADD 2 DYNAMIC BOXES HERE.... -->
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('blog-sidebar'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Looking forward to hearing form you with a good solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Share your code..

Comment: @pirs I have added the code to the post